# Triple monitor setup with an ATI Radeon 4200?

Tags: 10.10, xorg, multiple-monitors, ati

I have a relatively new Powerspec computer (i5 quad core processor, about a year or two old) and just grabbed a new relatively inexpensive ($40?) graphics card. It has 1 DVI, one VGA, and one HDMI output.

I have two (different type) monitors plugged into the DVI and VGA slots, and they work great. However, I cannot seem to be able to get a third monitor in the HDMI slot to work. I can see the monitor (and monitor info) show up in display settings. However, if I try to switch the monitor to 'on' and click apply, nothing happens.

Anyone have the slightest idea what the problem might be? (It's a Radeon graphics card FYI; if I remember right I think it was the Radeon 4200?)

Comment: Use the info from here to find out which card it is and add it to your question please: http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, based on the information in your question your card doesn't support three monitors.

The AMD/ATI technology for driving more than two monitors from the same card is called Eyefinity, but it is only supported on certain cards, see [AMD's Eyefinity FAQ](http://www.amd.com/US/PRODUCTS/TECHNOLOGIES/AMD-EYEFINITY-TECHNOLOGY/HOW-TO/Pages/faqs.aspx#products-support).

In brief, you need

- one of the Radeon models listed in the FAQ (all in the 5000 and 6000 series)
- **and** the card must have a DisplayPort connector.

The DisplayPort must be used for the third monitor.

In addition, [AMD does not officially support Eyefinity on Radeon cards for Linux](http://www.amd.com/US/PRODUCTS/TECHNOLOGIES/AMD-EYEFINITY-TECHNOLOGY/HOW-TO/Pages/faqs.aspx#tech-works-with) yet. Drivers [exist](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Features#EyeFinity), so with the proper combination of cards and monitors it can be made to work, but there are some limitations.

See also the question [3-monitor graphics on Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/229010/3-monitor-pci-e-graphics-card-on-linux-without-tremendous-pain) on superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to get a third monitor working using a USB video adapter from [DisplayLink](http://www.displaylink.com/). Take a look at [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10541762#post10541762) I just posted to get some feedback on the ease of doing this. My alternative is to get a 2nd PC and run Synergy to use the same mouse+keyboard with both systems :(

Here is the [DisplayLink on linux](http://libdlo.freedesktop.org/wiki/FrontPage) driver page